# What is wrong with this nested WHILE loop in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I ran into a weird situation today doing some one-time sql code. This nested loop doesn't seem to run the outer loop: it prints (0,0),(0,1),(0,2) and (0,3)

```
declare @i int, @j int
select @i = 0, @j = 0
while @i < 3 begin
    while @j < 3 begin
        select @i as i, @j as j
        set @j = @j + 1
    end
    set @i = @i + 1
end
```

Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Comment: Thanks for this Q! I needed a big smile today. ;-)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You are not resetting your j var for the next iteration

```
 set @i = @i + 1
 set @j = 0
```

Comment: Seven years later and here I am having the same duh moment

Comment: @dkwarr87 it's been 11 years and I'm keeping the tradition alive

Comment: I was going crazy until I found this. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You are not resetting @j.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @i int, @j int
select @i = 0, @j = 0 --<- Wrong place set @j
while @i < 3 
begin
    select @i, @j --<-test print, then you will know what happened~
    --set @j = 0 --<- Right place to set @j
    while @j < 3 
    begin
        select @i as i, @j as j
        set @j = @j + 1
    end
    set @i = @i + 1
end
```

The original result is 
0/0
0/0
0/1
0/2
1/3
2/3

Well, the above answered, just add code for more detail, lol~